# how to know the format of a date

Tags: sql-server, datetime

hi i am trying to update my tables consisting of dates i am encountering errors due to white spaces the date fields was given a varchar type by the pass programmer i want to convert my dates to this format `mm/dd/yyyy` but it seems the date fields are littered with this type of date APRIL 8, 2014 the question is how would i know that the date being updated are in this format sample APRIL 8, 2014? before updating it to proper format e.g mm/dd/yyyy

i have tried this SELECT convert(datetime, date_field, 101) but still it gives error

any suggestions?

Comment: if you've got mixed formats in the field, you're probably better off adding a new temp date field to the db and updating/converting into that new field so that the new column is entirely consistent. then you can replace the original mixed field with this new fixed field.

Comment: il do as you suggest and i will give an update thank you

Answer (score 0):

The date and time datatypes in SQL Server do not have any implicit format.  They are stored in an internal representation.  The formatting is only applied when they are presented to a user on-screen or in a report etc.  To store dates in a `varchar()` column was a mistake by the previous programmer which you should not repeat.  Add a new column to your table of type `date` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx).  Copy values from the current `varchar` to this new column, converting as you go.  Both these statements work

```
select CONVERT(date, 'APRIL 8, 2014')
select CONVERT(date, '04/08/2014')
```

To be sure these are the only combinations you should do some analysis on the current values using regular expressions (outside of SQL) or `SUBSTRING()` (inside SQL).

Drop the old `varchar` and rename the new `date` column.  You may have to drop and re-create constraints, indexes and foreign keys etc.

When passing these values back to the application keep them in date format.  Let the user interface or reporting application format the date however it needs to.

Comment: il do as you suggest and i will give an update thank you

Comment: additional question on the date given i am trying to do this  CASE WHEN ISDATE(dbo.tbl_arrest_information.date_arrested) > 0 THEN CAST(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, dbo.tbl_arrest_information.date_arrested) AS FLOAT) AS INT) ELSE NULL END AS MonthIntArr but it returns error can you please enlighten me thank you

Comment: I've submitted your code fragment to a 2008R2 instance using both date formats listed above.  I get back the answers I'd expect.  So without the schema definition, data that shows the error and the exact error message then no - I can't enlighten you.  Sorry.  If you would like further help I suggest you submit a new question with full details.